# Using vims tagbar plugin for latex files

Tags: vim, latex, osx-mavericks, ctags, tagbar

I am currently trying to make vim's tagbar plugin to work with latex files on Mac OS X.

This is my ~/.ctags file:

```
--langdef=latex
--langmap=latex:.tex
--regex-latex=/^\\tableofcontents/TABLE OF CONTENTS/s,toc/
--regex-latex=/^\\frontmatter/FRONTMATTER/s,frontmatter/
--regex-latex=/^\\mainmatter/MAINMATTER/s,mainmatter/
--regex-latex=/^\\backmatter/BACKMATTER/s,backmatter/
--regex-latex=/^\\bibliography\{/BIBLIOGRAPHY/s,bibliography/
--regex-latex=/^\\part[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/PART \2/s,part/
--regex-latex=/^\\part[[:space:]]*\*[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/PART \1/s,part/
--regex-latex=/^\\chapter[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/CHAP \2/s,chapter/
--regex-latex=/^\\chapter[[:space:]]*\*[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/CHAP \1/s,chapter/
--regex-latex=/^\\section[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\. \2/s,section/
--regex-latex=/^\\section[[:space:]]*\*[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\. \1/s,section/
--regex-latex=/^\\subsection[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\.\. \2/s,subsection/
--regex-latex=/^\\subsection[[:space:]]*\*[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\.\. \1/s,subsection/
--regex-latex=/^\\subsubsection[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\.\.\. \2/s,subsubsection/
--regex-latex=/^\\subsubsection[[:space:]]*\*[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\.\.\. \1/s,subsubsection/
--regex-latex=/^\\includegraphics[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\3/g,graphic+listing/
--regex-latex=/^\\lstinputlisting[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*(\[[^]]*\])?[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\3/g,graphic+listing/
--regex-latex=/\\label[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\1/l,label/
--regex-latex=/\\ref[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\1/r,ref/
--regex-latex=/\\pageref[[:space:]]*\{([^}]+)\}/\1/p,pageref/
```

and this is the corresponding part in my ~/.vimrc:

```
let g:tagbar_type_tex = {
    \ 'ctagstype' : 'latex',
    \ 'kinds'     : [
        \ 's:sections',
        \ 'g:graphics:0:0',
        \ 'l:labels',
        \ 'r:refs:1:0',
        \ 'p:pagerefs:1:0'
    \ ],
    \ 'sort'    : 0,
\ }
```

I basically got all this from this link: https://github.com/vim-scripts/Tagbar/blob/master/doc/tagbar.txt

Unfortunately, when I start the tagbar, nothing happens and when I execute :UpdateTags I get the following error:

```
easytags.vim 3.7: Exuberant Ctags doesn't support the 'plaintex' file type! (at function xolox#easytags#update..<SNR>20_check_cfile, line 22)
```

ctags --version results in:

```
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Oct  1 2014, 16:18:15
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

and "which ctags" in:

```
/usr/local/bin/ctags
```

When I execute ctags --verbose abstract.tex it finds the ~/.ctags file and generates this tag file:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8     //
. Abstract      abstract.tex    /^\\section*{Abstract}$/;"      s
```

The file itself looks like this:

```
\section*{Abstract}

Let's see what we can do here...
```

What am I missing? :(

Kind regards and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The EasyTags problem

1. EasyTags uses the filetype of the current buffer to determine what arguments it should pass to `ctags`.
2. The `filetype` of your file is set to `plaintex` by Vim, the default for `*.tex` files. So… you get that error because `plaintex` is not recognized by `ctags`.

### The Tagbar problem

1. As per [the documentation](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Tagbar/blob/master/doc/tagbar.txt#L937-L947), you are supposed to use the `filetype` in your custom configuration:

   ```
   g:tagbar_type_{vim filetype}
   ```
2. Since your `*.tex` file is recognized as `plaintex`, your `g:tagbar_type_tex` will never be used.

### A *liberal* solution

1. Add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` to force Vim to recognize `*.tex` files as `latex`:

   ```
   augroup latex
       autocmd!
       autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex set filetype=latex
   augroup END
   ```
2. Change your custom Tagbar config from:

   ```
   g:tagbar_type_tex
   ```

   to:

   ```
   g:tagbar_type_latex
   ```

*This solution will work only if Vim is configured to work well with the `latex` filetype (ftplugin, syntax, indent…), which is dubious at best.*

### A *conservative* solution

1. Use `plaintex` instead of `latex` in your `~/.ctags` configuration:

   ```
   --langdef=plaintex
   --langmap=plaintex:.tex
   --regex-plaintex=/^\\tableofcontents/TABLE OF CONTENTS/s,toc/
   ...
   ```
2. Change your custom Tagbar config from:

   ```
   let g:tagbar_type_tex = {
       \ 'ctagstype' : 'latex',
       ...
   ```

   to:

   ```
   let g:tagbar_type_plaintex = {
       \ 'ctagstype' : 'plaintex',
       ...
   ```